# Altering incoming Django url queries using tastypie : handling foreign key traversal on the backend

Tags: django, tastypie

So we've got a Django/tastypie server going that has the following (simplified) model. If I remove our `alter_detail_data_to_serialize`:

```
{
   "release": false, 
   "resource_uri": "/api/packages/1", 
   "id": 1, 
   "branch": {
      "resource_uri": "/api/branches/1", 
      "id": 1, 
      # ... more bits the client doesn't need to know about
      "version": "0.1"
   }, 
   "revision": "72"
}
```

With the alter, it becomes:

```
{
   "release": false, 
   "branch": "0.1", 
   "revision": "72"
}
```

Which is what we want to work with through the API: It removes the foreign key traversal to simplify the JSON and do any CRUD without issues: supplying a `version` is sufficient to identify the branch. The issue is, to query this, requires 
`/api/packages?branch__version=1.0`, where this not intuitive and exposes the structure of the underlying database. We'd prefer to be able to query:
`/api/packages?branch=1.0` and handle the foreign key traversal on the backend.

`alter_detail_data_to_serialize` and `alter_deserialized_detail_data` allow me to interface with the simplified JSON and do any non-searching CRUD without issues, but is it possible to allow a `/api/packages?branch=1.0` query and have the django/tastypie server correct that to `/api/packages?branch__version=1.0`, hiding the database structure?

Some additional code that might be relevant:

```
class PackageResource(ModelResource):
    branch = fields.ForeignKey(BranchResource, 'branch', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Packages.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'packages'
        collection_name = 'packages'

    def alter_detail_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        data.data['branch'] = data.data['branch'].data['version']
        return data
```

Branch Resource:

```
class BranchResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Branches.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'branches'
        collection_name = 'branches'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the object resource, you can add something like this:

```
class PackageResourse(ModelResource):
    version = fields.CharField( attribute = 'branch__version' )
    class Meta:
      resource_name='package'
```

What this is doing it making the `PackageResource` have a variable that is the same as its foreign key's variable. Now you can use `api/packages?version=1.0` on the `PackageResource`.

Comment: So it's currently: 
`class PackageResource(ModelResource):
    branch = fields.ForeignKey(BranchResource, 'branch', full=True)` and I need the foreign key to be able to look up the value, or am I mistaken?
EDIT: Putting in `fields.ForeignKey(BranchResource, 'branch__version', full=True)` yields: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: You can leave the `fields.ForeignKey`, because I am not sure what else you are doing with that. What I am reccomendind you to is add a new field to the resource for only the version number. That way you can pass params the way you requested. I will update my answer to further clarify.

Comment: Let me know if this is not completely clear, I am happy to keep revising to help this make sense.

Comment: EDIT: I have been able to get this working. I'm gonna run through some tests to see if there are any issues. Thanks for your assistance :)